# Fuse.js to search in array with dot in keys

Tags: javascript, fuse.js

Im using fetch on a Rest endpoint which gives me a array of objects. All the keys in the array has a dot in them. ex: {test.name: "test"}. I have to keep fetching new responses to get changes so while i can remove or replace the dot this will take some time/resources every time. Is there any way to use keys with dots in fuse.js?

I tried some variants of this with no luck.

```
const fuse = new Fuse(this.state.test, {
    keys: ['test.name']
});
```

ps. I cant change the keys in the Rest as its external

Comment: If anyone have a similar issue i still could not find a way to use it with fuse,  but the workaround is replacing the dot e.g: `key.replace(".", "_")`. I used this as i had a list of objects  `function transformKeys(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(o, prop) {
        var value = obj[prop];
        var newProp = prop.replace('.', '_');
        o[newProp] = value;
        return o;
    }, {});
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Fuse.js v6.3.0 you can search through nested values by providing the path via dot (`.`) **or** array notation. Therefore, if your key already has a dot in it, you can wrap it in an array:

```js
const fuse = new Fuse(this.state.test, {
  // `test.name` is the actual key, so wrap it in an array
  keys: [['test.name']]
});
```